# RSpec & Shoulda one-liner description output

Tags: tdd, rspec2, shoulda

A one-liner in RSpec such as...

```
it { should validate_presence_of(:title) }
```

...produces the descriptive output of:

```
"should require title to be set"
```

The [line of code](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/master/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_model/validate_presence_of_matcher.rb#L36) within the matcher for this example does not prefixed the output with "should" so this must be injected by RSpec.

I'd like to remove the "should" prefix all together for my one-liners but can't find a RSpec config option or the location in RSpec's code that the injection is performed.

Has anyone done this in the past with RSpec?

Comment: The code that prefixes 'should' is in the RSpec::Matchers.generated_description:
https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/master/lib/rspec/matchers/generated_descriptions.rb